# Why my program return different results at optimization level of O0 and O2

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>

const int & Min(const int& a, const int& b);


int main() {
    using namespace std;

    auto&& val = Min(1,2);

    cout << val << endl;
    return 0;
}


const int & Min(const int& a, const int& b) {
    return a < b ? a : b;
}
```

If I compile this with O0 option, `g++ -O0 main.cpp -o main`, the result is `1`. If I compile with O2 option, `g++ -O2 main.cpp -o main`, this will give a result of 0.

Why this give different results ?

Comment: take a look at the assembler code.

Comment: See also: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min#Warning

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk assembler code is not a good source to solve UB problems

Comment: You forgot `-Wall`, then you would see a warning at -O2.

Answer (score 14):

Your code has [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

For `Min(1,2);`, two temporary objects initialized from `1` and `2` are constructed and then bound to the reference parameter `a` and `b`. Note that the temporary objects are destroyed immediately (after the full expression). `Min()` returns either `a` or `b` by reference; that means the returned reference is always dangled, dereference on it leads to UB, i.e. anything is possible.

**EDIT**

Literals (like `1` and `2`) can't be bound to reference directly, [temporary](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime) is needed instead,

> Temporary objects are created `when a prvalue is materialized so that
>   it can be used as a glvalue, which occurs (since C++17)` in the
>   following situations:
>
> - binding a reference to a prvalue

Comment: Why is there temporary objects initialized from 1 and 2, since they are instant numbers ? I passed them by reference, why are they still temporary ?

Comment: Got it, then how could I make this function accept reference as well as instant numbers ? What is the correct form of this function ?

Comment: @coincheung Using it like `auto val = Min(1,2);` would be fine, i.e. don't capture the return value by reference. Or change the return type from `const int&` to `int`.

Comment: Does this mean that the numbers ```1``` and ```2``` live from calling the function ```Min(1,2)``` to returning a value ? They are only destroyed after the returning is finished and the function stack moves back, and it the process of doing operations in the function body, they are still alive and available ?

Comment: @coincheung Yes the temporaries constructed from `1` and `2` will be destroyed after the full expression `auto&& val = Min(1,2);`, before the next expression `cout << val << endl;`. So they're alive in the body of `Min`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation !! I dare say this procedure of generating a temporary object even for a instant number will bring some overhead and makes c++ slower than they are expected, is that true ?

Comment: @coincheung This is a challenging question indeed but I believe the answer is *no*. Especially when you understand how references and literals work in C++.

Comment: @coincheung Even you change the parameter type to pass-by-value, i.e. `int  Min(int a, int b);`, with `Min(1, 2)`, two objects will be copy constructed from `1` and `2` and then used as the parameter `a` and `b`.